# text fitting the expandedlist header's width

Tags: dart, flutter

am using my customized ExpandedList .. but the header is overflowed when the text is long ....

[image]

and this is how am using it:

```
new CustomExpansionPanelList2(
                          expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                            setState(() {
                              faqList[index].isExpanded =
                                  !faqList[index].isExpanded;
                            });
                          },
                          children: faqList.map((Faq i) {
                            return new ExpansionPanel(
                              headerBuilder:
                                  (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                                return new Container(
                                  child: new Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      SizedBox(child: Text(
                                        i.question,
                                        style:
                                        TextStyle(color: Color(0xff606060)),
                                      ),),

                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              isExpanded: i.isExpanded,
                              body: new Center(
                                child: new Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: Text(i.answer),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
```

I want the text to be in two lines or more is needed to make it fit the width of the Expanded list..

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `SizedBox` by Expanded in the `headerBuilder`

```
        return new Container(
                                          child: new Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Expanded(child: Text(
                                                i.question,
                                                style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Color(0xff606060)),
                                              ),),

                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
```